# Test AWS lambda container image locally

Tags: docker, aws-lambda

I am having an issue when I run a docker image locally.I've a simple AWS lambda as an image in the ECR repo.Basically what I did is downloaded this image using docker pull command and tried to run the image using docker run command.

```
docker pull 35xxxxxx5770.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/demo- 
lambda:1.0.0
```

I am getting the below when I run it.I was expecting an output from the print statements.

```
docker run 31343415770.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/demo-lambda:1.0.0
```

[INFO] (rapid) exec '/var/runtime/bootstrap' (cwd=/var/task, handler=)

Below is my lambda function code in a file called "app.py".

```
def handler(event, context) -> None:
    print("\nIam from app.py")
    print('\nevent: ', event)
    print('\ncontext: ', context)
```

And my Dockerfile looks like this.

```
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir \
    --trusted-host pypi.org \
    --trusted-host pypi.python.org \
    --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org \
    --upgrade pip

COPY . .
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir \
--trusted-host pypi.org \
--trusted-host pypi.python.org \
--trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org \
-r requirements.txt \
--target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"

# Copy function code
COPY ./app.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/
CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

Any help in solving this error much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. Please don't just provide a link. Explain your issue, show what you've tried and how you've implemented and troubleshot the issue. It will make it much easier to attempt to find a solution. You can probably just edit your previous question / answer and copy paste it all here.

Comment: Thank you for updating. I don't see an error here. In fact, it looks like everything is operating normally. Have you tried invoking the handler? Something like `curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{}'`?

Comment: Thank you. I really don't have any end point, so not sure what do I fill in place of localhost?

Comment: Also I am not very certain the below lines were errors when I run the image locally.           
[INFO] (rapid) exec '/var/runtime/bootstrap' (cwd=/var/task, handler=). My initial thought was it would execute the lambda handler and output the print statement from it.

Comment: I also tried curl command as you mentioned. curl -XPOST "localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/…" -d '{}'. This is throwing error "404 page not found" –